# Difference between f(s::String) and f(::String)

Tags: syntax, julia

What is the difference between the following two functions?

```
julia> one(s::String) = return 1
one (generic function with 1 method)

julia> one(::String) = return 1
one (generic function with 1 method)
```

Both seem to be allowed and there doesn't seem to be a difference between them. I suppose not including the `v` could signal to the compiler that the value of the argument is not used, but then again this is something the compiler can figure out, right? (Disclaimer: I have no idea how compilers work)

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference if you don't use the argument, and yes, for the compiler this should be trivial.

You can use `_` as an actual "discard argument" though, and the parser will prevent you from using it:

```
julia> f(_) = _ + 1
ERROR: syntax: all-underscore identifier used as rvalue around REPL[9]:1
```

That's useful in some situations:

```
julia> _, _, z = (1,2,3)
(1, 2, 3)

julia> z
3

julia> _
ERROR: all-underscore identifier used as rvalue
```

while

```
julia> x, x, z = (1,2,3)
(1, 2, 3)

julia> x
2
```

is slightly confusing.

---

### More technicalities

An unused argument is preseved in IR, though:

```
julia> one(::String) = return 1
one (generic function with 1 method)

julia> one2(s::String) = return 1
one2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> ir = @code_lowered one("sdf")
CodeInfo(
1 ─     return 1
)

julia> ir.slotnames
2-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 Symbol("#self#")  
 Symbol("#unused#")

julia> ir2 = @code_lowered one2("sdf")
CodeInfo(
1 ─     return 1
)

julia> ir2.slotnames
2-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 Symbol("#self#")
 :s
```

If you ever care about slot names.  I can't imagine how this would change further compilation, but it can be a corner case in metaprogramming.

Comment: Actually e.g. Pipe.jl takes advantage of the fact that `_` is write-only.